# Use String variable in IN clause MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to use variable in IN Clause of mysql ? I know i can use find_in_set function but i don't want to use that as it validates all the rows.
Even i don't want to build query, prepare it and execute. Is there any other way i can do ? (In clause items are varchar not int)

Comment: Look for dynamic SQL (ie. build, prepare and execute. Why don't you want to do that?)

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to feed in an array and have 'prepare' build an `IN` list.  Alas, you need to write custom code to do such.  What language are you using?